# How to get lat & lng value from address given by user using GMSMapView in iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps

I have 2 `UITextField` for putting From location & To location. And when user click getDirection button that time i need that 2 input location latitude and longitude value and draw a path and drop a pin also. I am creating all the things but facing 1 problem. I am getting first lat, long value 0.0000, 0.0000 for that i am unable to draw a path. I can able to draw a path but its drawing 3 lines like from (0,0) to to location lat, long then from location lat, long. I share my code and my output screenshot please guide me what i have to do.

// For getDirection Btn Action

```
-(void)DirectionBtn_Clicked
{    
  NSString *from_Location = self.fromDestinationField.text;
  NSString *to_Location = self.toDestinationField.text;

  [self getLatLong:from_Location];
  [self getLatLong:to_Location];
  [mapView_ clear];
}

-(void)getLatLong:(NSString *)string
{
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:string completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
 {
    if([placemarks count])
    {
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
        NSLog(@"coordinate = (%f, %f)", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);
        if([string isEqualToString:self.fromDestinationField.text])
        {
            fromLat = coordinate.latitude;
            fromLng = coordinate.longitude;
            [self display];
        }
        else if([string  isEqualToString:self.toDestinationField.text])
        {
            toLat = coordinate.latitude;
            toLng = coordinate.longitude;
            [self display];
        }
     }
   }];
 }
 - (void)display
 {
   GMSMarker *fromLocationPin = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
   fromLocationPin.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(fromLat, fromLng);
   fromLocationPin.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
   fromLocationPin.title = self.fromDestinationField.text;
   fromLocationPin.map = mapView_;

   GMSMarker *toLocationPin = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
   toLocationPin.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(toLat, toLng);
   toLocationPin.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor magentaColor]];
   toLocationPin.title = self.toDestinationField.text;
   toLocationPin.map = mapView_;

   GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:toLat longitude:toLng zoom:6];
   [mapView_ animateToCameraPosition:camera];

   [self getValueforDrawPathFromlat:fromLat Fromlong:fromLng Tolat:toLat Tolong:toLng];

}

-(void)getValueforDrawPathFromlat:(CGFloat)fromLoc_lat Fromlong:(CGFloat)fromLoc_lng Tolat:(CGFloat)toLoc_lat Tolong:(CGFloat)toLng_lat
{
  NSLog(@"%f",fromLoc_lat);
  NSLog(@"%f",fromLoc_lng);
  NSLog(@"%f",toLoc_lat);
  NSLog(@"%f",toLng_lat);

  GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
  [path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(fromLoc_lat, fromLoc_lng)];
  [path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(toLoc_lat, toLng_lat)];

  GMSPolyline *rectangle = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
  rectangle.strokeWidth = 2.f;
  rectangle.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  rectangle.map = mapView_;
  self.view = mapView_;
}
```

My output is like this:

[image]

I don't need that long line which is draw from (0,0) coordinate to my FromLocation coordinate. Every time its create a unnecessary line.

And my out put is like this:

```
 2014-09-10 17:02:07.549 GoogleMapSample[4575:70b] coordinate = (12.976746, 77.575278)
 2014-09-10 17:02:07.553 GoogleMapSample[4575:70b] 12.976747
 2014-09-10 17:02:07.553 GoogleMapSample[4575:70b] 77.575279
 2014-09-10 17:02:07.553 GoogleMapSample[4575:70b] 0.000000
 2014-09-10 17:02:07.553 GoogleMapSample[4575:70b] 0.000000
 2014-09-10 17:02:09.494 GoogleMapSample[4575:70b] coordinate = (20.244364, 85.817781)
 2014-09-10 17:02:09.496 GoogleMapSample[4575:70b] 12.976747
 2014-09-10 17:02:09.496 GoogleMapSample[4575:70b] 77.575279
 2014-09-10 17:02:09.496 GoogleMapSample[4575:70b] 20.244364
 2014-09-10 17:02:09.497 GoogleMapSample[4575:70b] 85.817780
```

Fir this 0.00000 its showing this path. How to avoid this one ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why is the code calling `[self display];` after setting fromLat and fromLng?  At that point, toLat and toLng haven't been set yet.  Also note that geocodeAddressString is asynchronous so there's no guarantee the geocode of the From address will be done before the To address is geocoded (you need to rearrange the code a bit).  Also, why is the code calling `[mapView_ clear];` _after_ the pins and route are drawn?

Comment: Please can u suggest me what i have to do?